# Updating Swing GUI from thread

Tags: java, swing

I have a simple application with some threads, I need tu update SWING GUI (I'm using Netbeans) from some thread.

This is my main form which i need to update:

```
public class mainForm extends javax.swing.JFrame {
private gameControll obj;
  public mainForm() {

    initComponents();
}
 public void runAuto(){
ThreadTest th1 = new ThreadTest(1, 1, obj);
ThreadTest th8 = new ThreadTest(8, 95000, obj);
ThreadTest th2 = new ThreadTest(2, 100000, obj);
ThreadTest th3 = new ThreadTest(3, 120000, obj);
ThreadTest th4 = new ThreadTest(4, 140000, obj);
ThreadTest th22 = new ThreadTest(22, 1000, obj);

Thread thread1 = new Thread(th1);
Thread thread2 = new Thread(th2);
Thread thread3 = new Thread(th3);
Thread thread4 = new Thread(th4);
Thread thread22 = new Thread(th22);
Thread thread8 = new Thread(th8);

thread1.start();
thread2.start();
thread3.start();
thread4.start();
thread22.start();
thread8.start();

}
public static void main(String args[]) {

SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
  public void run() {
    mainForm app = new mainForm();
    app.setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
private javax.swing.JButton jButton10;
private javax.swing.JButton jButton2;
private javax.swing.JButton jButton3;
private javax.swing.JButton jButton4;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel4;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel5;
private javax.swing.JSeparator jSeparator1;
private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField1;
private javax.swing.JTextField pathtbox;                 
}
```

Now i have some threads:

```
public class ThreadTest implements Runnable {
public static mainForm main = new mainForm();
private final int functionNumber;
private final int time2start;
public ThreadTest(int functionNumber, int time2start, gameControll obj){
this.functionNumber = functionNumber;
this.time2start = time2start;

}

   @Override
   public void run(){

try{Thread.sleep(time2start);}catch(Exception ex){}//Time Delay before executing methods
switch(functionNumber){
    case 1:
//System.out.println("case 1");
        obj.runFirst();
        break;
    case 2:
   //     System.out.println("case 2");
        obj.runSecond();

        break;
    case 3:

{
    try {
        obj.runThird();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(ThreadTest.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
        break;
...
```

ANd in some other class i have:

```
  public void runFirst(){
   System.out.println("I need to show this text on jlabel5");
   }
```

Each part of the code is in different file (class).
How would i implement Swing worker here to be able to show text on my main GUI form?

Comment: You might want to take a look at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html#invokeLater(java.lang.Runnable), which performs an operation on the GUI thread.

Comment: I can't really finD anything there as I am beginner in Java, i have tried but without success. The documentation for beginners is not really readable. A simple piece of code based on my example would be awesome if someone can write it. If not i'll continue to google.

Comment: @BlankName, Henrik linked a specific method's documentation. Did you read it? You can update your GUI from a non-EDT thread by wrapping code that accesses Swing components into an implementation of `java.lang.Runnable` and passing an instance of that to `SwingUtilities.invokeLater(Runnable)`.

Comment: I have read that but I can't seem to find a way to implement that in my App... as I said i'm beginner in Java.

Answer (score 1):

> *How would i implement Swing worker here to be able to show text on my main GUI form?*

Based on this list of features observed in your code:

- You want an initial delay to perform tasks.
- Tasks are intended to be performed in a sequential order.
- Tasks are intended to update GUI components but not to perform heavy tasks (i.e.: set a label's text).

IMO [Swing Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) suits better than Swing worker in this case. Instead of having a class implementing `Runnable` interface you could define several timers with access to the `MainForm` class instance in order to perform the desired actions and update the very same form (right now you create a new form as a class member of `ThreadTest` class). For example:

```
    Timer timer1 = new Timer(1, new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            mainFrame.runFirst();
        }
    });
    timer1.setRepeats(false);

    Timer timer2 = new Timer(1000, new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            mainFrame.runSecond();
        }
    });
    timer2.setRepeats(false);
    ...
    timer1.start();
    timer2.start();
    ...
```

Where `MainFrame#runFirst()` should look like this:

```
public void runFirst() {
    jlabel5.setText("Label#5 updated from Timer!");
}
```

Comment: I am calling obj which is separate class, it's called "gameControll" i guess i can't update label text from the other class?

Comment: It depends... you can as long as you keep a reference to `mainContronl` class in your `gameControll` class. The question is what really do `runFirst()`, `runSecond()`... methods do? If those methods just update the GUI *without* any heavy processing stuff then the approach still valid. If those methods do a complex/time consuming logic and then update the GUI then a SwingWorker would be better. @BlankName

Comment: Those methods just wait certain period and then execute simple tasks, write to text file, etc...